# Insert Month into data

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a large section of code that I declare an insert date of at the beginning:

```
DECLARE @lcid INT 
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME=@10
DECLARE @enddate DATETIME=@11
DECLARE @PitchJobTypeId INT
DECLARE @ClientInvestmentJobTypeId INT
DECLARE @AdministrationJobTypeId INT

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#data') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #data


DECLARE @Billablejob TABLE(
id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
Jobid INT)


DECLARE @Department table(
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
DepartmentId INT)

IF @10 > @11
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Error in date selection' AS 'Error';
    GOTO ExitSp;
END



INSERT INTO @Billablejob(Jobid)
SELECT distinct s.Element FROM dbo.Split(@30,',') AS s

Insert into @Department(DepartmentId)
SELECT distinct s.Element FROM dbo.Split(@5,',') AS s
IF EXISTS(SELECT '' FROM @Department AS d WHERE d.DepartmentId=0) OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT '' FROM @Department AS d) BEGIN
    DELETE FROM @Department
    INSERT INTO @Department(DepartmentId)
    SELECT rsa.AfdID FROM RessSelAfd AS rsa --INNER JOIN @comp c ON c.compid=rsa.SelID  
END

IF @20 IS NULL SET @20=0



CREATE TABLE #data(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
[Name]  nvarchar(MAX),
[Employee Type] nvarchar(MAX),
[Basic Time] money,
[Used Time] MONEY,
[Holiday] MONEY,
[Recovery] MONEY,
[Illness] MONEY,
[Billable Time] MONEY,
[Non Billable Time] MONEY,
[Pitch Time] MONEY,
[Internal Time] MONEY,
[Used Time2] MONEY,
[Max Billable Hours] MONEY,
[Available Hours] MONEY,
[Office Hours %] INT,
[Billable %] INT,
[Non Billable %] INT,
[Pitch %] INT,
[Internal %] INT,
[Billable Target %] INT,
[Variance to Target %] INT,
[Department] NVARCHAR(max),
[Job Role] NVARCHAR(max),
[Market] NVARCHAR(max),
EmpId INT,
DepartmentId INT,
JobRoleId INT,
MarketId INT,
IsActive BIT,
Hiredate DATETIME,
Expirydate DATETIME,
EmployeeType INT
)

IF @10>@11 BEGIN
SELECT 'Date selection error' Error
GOTO ExitSp
END

SELECT @PitchJobTypeId = sj.JobTypeID FROM SysJobtype AS sj WHERE sj.JobtypeNavn='Pitch'

IF @PitchJobTypeId IS NULL BEGIN
SELECT 'Jobtype ''Pitch'' not found' Error
GOTO ExitSp
END

SELECT @ClientInvestmentJobTypeId = sj.JobTypeID FROM SysJobtype AS sj WHERE sj.JobtypeNavn='Client Investment'

IF @ClientInvestmentJobTypeId IS NULL BEGIN
SELECT 'Jobtype ''Client Investment'' not found' Error
GOTO ExitSp
END

SELECT @AdministrationJobTypeId = sj.JobTypeID FROM SysJobtype AS sj WHERE sj.JobtypeNavn='Administration'

IF @AdministrationJobTypeId IS NULL BEGIN
SELECT 'Jobtype ''Administration'' not found' Error
GOTO ExitSp
END




SELECT @lcid=InterfaceLcid FROM ress WHERE ressid=@UserId

INSERT INTO #data( empid,[Name],[Billable Target %],[JobRoleId],[Job Role],DepartmentId,MarketId,IsActive,Hiredate,Expirydate,EmployeeType,[Employee Type])
SELECT emp.empid,EmpName,(SELECT TOP 1 ehp.ProfitTarget*100 FROM EmpHrsPrice AS ehp WHERE ehp.EmpId = emp.empid AND ehp.ValidFrom <= @enddate ORDER BY ehp.ValidFrom desc),emppost.PostId,

(SELECT ISNULL(nullif(ActLang.ActTxt,''), Act.ActTxt)
    FROM    Act 
        LEFT JOIN ActLang 
            ON Act.AID = ActLang.Aid
            AND ActLang.LCID=@LCID
    WHERE   Act.AID=emp.aid),emp.DepartmentId,emp.CompId,emp.IsActive,emp.Hiredate,emp.Expirydate,emp.EmployTypeId,CASE WHEN et.enumval=1 OR et.enumval=2 THEN 'Permanent' ELSE 'Freelance' END FROM emp 
INNER JOIN ress ON ress.RessID=emp.EmpId 
INNER JOIN @Department AS d ON d.DepartmentId = Emp.DepartmentId
LEFT JOIN emppost ON emp.PostId=emppost.PostId
LEFT JOIN EnumTable(467) AS et ON et.EnumVal=emp.EmployTypeId
WHERE (IsActive=1 OR (Expirydate>=@startdate and Expirydate<=@enddate)) AND (CASE WHEN emp.EmployTypeId=2 THEN 1 ELSE emp.EmployTypeId END=@20 OR @20=0) AND Ress.UserAcountType<>5

UPDATE d SET d.Department=rsa.AfdNavn FROM #data d INNER JOIN RessSelAfd AS rsa ON d.DepartmentId=rsa.AfdID

UPDATE d SET d.Market=comp.CompName FROM #data d INNER JOIN comp ON d.MarketId=comp.compid

UPDATE d SET d.[Basic Time]=data.HrsNorm FROM #data d INNER JOIN
(SELECT cap.ResId,Sum(ISNULL(Cap.HrsNorm,0)+ISNULL(Cap.HrsHoli,0)) AS HrsNorm FROM cap INNER JOIN #data d ON d.empid=cap.ResId AND CAST(DayDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
GROUP BY cap.ResId) data ON d.EmpId=data.ResId

UPDATE d SET d.[Used Time]=data.UsedHours FROM #data d INNER JOIN
(SELECT tr.EmpId,SUM(tr.RegHrs) AS UsedHours FROM TimeReg AS tr WHERE CAST(RegDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
and reghrs IS NOT null
GROUP BY tr.EmpId ) data ON d.EmpId=data.EmpId

UPDATE d SET [Basic Time]=[Used Time],d.[Billable Target %]=100 FROM #data d WHERE EmployeeType=3

UPDATE d SET [Basic Time]=ISNULL([Basic Time],0),[Used Time]=ISNULL([Used Time],0) FROM #data d 

UPDATE d
SET d.Holiday = data.UsedHours
FROM #data d
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tr.EmpId,SUM(tr.RegHrs) AS UsedHours
    FROM TimeReg AS tr
    INNER JOIN RessFerie AS rf ON rf.RecId=tr.EmpHoliRecId
    INNER JOIN AbsenceCode AS ac ON ac.Id=rf.AbsenceID
    INNER JOIN job ON Job.JobID = tr.JobId
    INNER JOIN RessProjekter AS rp ON rp.ProjektID = Job.ProjektID
    INNER JOIN CUST ON cust.CustId=rp.RessID    
    WHERE CAST(RegDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND RegHrs IS NOT NULL AND cust.CustTypeId=5 AND job.JobTypeID<>@PitchJobTypeId AND ac.Descr<>'Recovery Day'
    GROUP BY tr.EmpId
) data ON d.EmpId = data.EmpId;

UPDATE d
SET d.Recovery = data.UsedHours
FROM #data d
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tr.EmpId,SUM(tr.RegHrs) AS UsedHours
    FROM TimeReg AS tr
    INNER JOIN RessFerie AS rf ON rf.RecId=tr.EmpHoliRecId
    INNER JOIN AbsenceCode AS ac ON ac.Id=rf.AbsenceID
    INNER JOIN job ON Job.JobID = tr.JobId
    INNER JOIN RessProjekter AS rp ON rp.ProjektID = Job.ProjektID
    INNER JOIN CUST ON cust.CustId=rp.RessID    
    WHERE CAST(RegDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND RegHrs IS NOT NULL AND cust.CustTypeId=5 AND job.JobTypeID<>@PitchJobTypeId AND ac.Descr='Recovery Day'
    GROUP BY tr.EmpId
) data ON d.EmpId = data.EmpId;

UPDATE d
SET d.Illness = data.UsedHours
FROM #data d
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tr.EmpId,SUM(tr.RegHrs) AS UsedHours
    FROM TimeReg AS tr
    INNER JOIN job ON Job.JobID = tr.JobId
    INNER JOIN RessProjekter AS rp ON rp.ProjektID = Job.ProjektID
    INNER JOIN CUST ON cust.CustId=rp.RessID
    WHERE CAST(RegDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND RegHrs IS NOT NULL AND cust.CustTypeId=6 AND job.JobTypeID<>@PitchJobTypeId
    GROUP BY tr.EmpId
) data ON d.EmpId = data.EmpId;

UPDATE d
SET d.[Billable Time] = data.UsedHours
FROM #data d
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tr.EmpId,SUM(tr.RegHrs) AS UsedHours
    FROM TimeReg AS tr
    INNER JOIN job ON Job.JobID = tr.JobId
    INNER JOIN RessProjekter AS rp ON rp.ProjektID = Job.ProjektID
    INNER JOIN CUST ON cust.CustId=rp.RessID
    LEFT JOIN @Billablejob AS bj ON job.JobID=bj.Jobid
    WHERE CAST(RegDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND RegHrs IS NOT NULL AND (job.DebitFlg=1 OR bj.Jobid IS NOT NULL) AND (cust.CustTypeId=1 OR cust.CustTypeId=2) AND job.JobTypeID<>@PitchJobTypeId AND job.JobTypeID<>@ClientInvestmentJobTypeId AND job.JobTypeID<>@AdministrationJobTypeId
    GROUP BY tr.EmpId
) data ON d.EmpId = data.EmpId;

UPDATE d
SET d.[Non Billable Time] = data.UsedHours
FROM #data d
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tr.EmpId,SUM(tr.RegHrs) AS UsedHours
    FROM TimeReg AS tr
    INNER JOIN job ON Job.JobID = tr.JobId
    INNER JOIN RessProjekter AS rp ON rp.ProjektID = Job.ProjektID
    INNER JOIN CUST ON cust.CustId=rp.RessID
    LEFT JOIN @Billablejob AS bj ON job.JobID=bj.Jobid
    WHERE CAST(RegDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND RegHrs IS NOT NULL AND ((bj.Jobid IS NULL and job.DebitFlg=0 AND (cust.CustTypeId=1 OR cust.CustTypeId=2) AND job.JobTypeID<>@PitchJobTypeId AND job.JobTypeID<>@AdministrationJobTypeId)  OR job.JobTypeID=@ClientInvestmentJobTypeId)
    GROUP BY tr.EmpId
) data ON d.EmpId = data.EmpId;

UPDATE d
SET d.[Pitch Time] = data.UsedHours
FROM #data d
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tr.EmpId,SUM(tr.RegHrs) AS UsedHours
    FROM TimeReg AS tr
    INNER JOIN job ON Job.JobID = tr.JobId
    INNER JOIN RessProjekter AS rp ON rp.ProjektID = Job.ProjektID
    INNER JOIN CUST ON cust.CustId=rp.RessID
    WHERE CAST(RegDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND RegHrs IS NOT NULL AND tr.EmpHoliRecId IS NULL AND job.JobTypeID=@PitchJobTypeId
    GROUP BY tr.EmpId
) data ON d.EmpId = data.EmpId;

UPDATE d
SET d.[Internal Time] = data.UsedHours
FROM #data d
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tr.EmpId,SUM(tr.RegHrs) AS UsedHours
    FROM TimeReg AS tr
    INNER JOIN job ON Job.JobID = tr.JobId
    INNER JOIN RessProjekter AS rp ON rp.ProjektID = Job.ProjektID
    INNER JOIN CUST ON cust.CustId=rp.RessID
    WHERE CAST(RegDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND RegHrs IS NOT NULL AND tr.EmpHoliRecId IS NULL AND (((cust.CustTypeId=3 OR cust.CustTypeId=4) AND job.JobTypeID<>@PitchJobTypeId AND job.JobTypeID<>@ClientInvestmentJobTypeId) OR job.JobTypeID=@AdministrationJobTypeId)
    GROUP BY tr.EmpId
) data ON d.EmpId = data.EmpId;

UPDATE d SET d.[Used Time2]=isnull(d.[Used Time],0)-isnull(d.Recovery,0) FROM #data d

UPDATE d SET d.[Max Billable Hours]=ISNULL(d.[Used Time2],0)-ISNULL(d.Holiday,0)-ISNULL(d.Illness,0) FROM #data d

UPDATE d SET d.[Available Hours]=ISNULL(d.[Basic Time],0)-ISNULL(d.Holiday,0)-ISNULL(d.Illness,0) FROM #data d

UPDATE d SET d.[Office Hours %]=CAST(CASE WHEN ISNULL(d.[Available Hours],0)=0 THEN 0 ELSE d.[Max Billable Hours]/d.[Available Hours]*100 END AS INT) FROM #data d

UPDATE d SET d.[Billable %]=CAST(CASE WHEN ISNULL(d.[Available Hours],0)=0 THEN CASE WHEN ISNULL(d.[Billable Time],0)=0 THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ELSE d.[Billable Time]/d.[Available Hours]*100 END AS INT) FROM #data d

UPDATE d SET d.[Non Billable %]=CAST(CASE WHEN ISNULL(d.[Available Hours],0)=0 THEN 0 ELSE d.[Non Billable Time]/d.[Available Hours]*100 END AS INT) FROM #data d

UPDATE d SET d.[Pitch %]=CAST(CASE WHEN ISNULL(d.[Available Hours],0)=0 THEN 0 ELSE d.[Pitch Time]/d.[Available Hours]*100 END AS INT) FROM #data d

UPDATE d SET d.[Internal %]=CAST(CASE WHEN ISNULL(d.[Available Hours],0)=0 THEN 0 ELSE d.[Internal Time]/d.[Available Hours]*100 END AS INT) FROM #data d

UPDATE d SET d.[Variance to Target %]=ISNULL(d.[Billable %],0)-ISNULL(d.[Billable Target %],0) FROM #data d


SELECT d.Name,
       d.[Employee Type],
       d.[Basic Time],
       d.[Used Time] AS [Total Time posted],
       isnull(d.Holiday,0)+isnull(d.Illness,0) [Absence],
       d.Recovery,
       d.[Billable Time],
       d.[Non Billable Time],
       d.[Pitch Time],
       d.[Internal Time],
       isnull(d.[Used Time2],0) AS [Used Time],
       d.[Max Billable Hours],
       d.[Available Hours],
       CAST(d.[Office Hours %] AS NVARCHAR(50))+'%' AS [Office Hours %],
       CAST(d.[Billable %] AS NVARCHAR(50))+'%' AS [Billable %],
       CAST(d.[Non Billable %] AS NVARCHAR(50))+'%' AS [Non Billable %],
       CAST(d.[Pitch %] AS NVARCHAR(50))+'%' AS [Pitch %],
       CAST(d.[Internal %] AS NVARCHAR(50))+'%' AS [Internal %],
       CAST(d.[Billable Target %] AS NVARCHAR(50))+'%' AS [Billable Target %],
       CAST(d.[Variance to Target %] AS NVARCHAR(50))+'%' AS [Variance to Target %],
       d.Department,
       d.[Job Role],
       d.Market
       FROM #data d



ExitSp:
```

This forces the user to pick a date range before pulling back the data.

An example of the data received back is:

[image]

What is the best way to then mark this data with the Month of the range the user picks?

For example if they choose **startdate 01/01/2019** and **enddate 16/01/2019** all records would be marked with an extra column showing Jan 2019 or something similar.

Additionally if there was a selection that spanned multiple months eg. **01/01/2019 to 20/02/2019** this would mark those relating to Jan and those relating to Feb in a new column?

Example of desired result:

[image]

Many thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where the `SELECT` getting the results shown happens in your very lengthy code, so you have to figure out where this goes yourself. But for getting the name of the month and the year a date is in one possibility is to use [`datename()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`concat()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) the two together.

```
concat(datename(month, <your date column>), ' ', datename(year, <your date column>))
```

Replace `<your date column>` with the column that holds the date you want to show the month and year of.